# is it possible to make $(Df_x(V_1(x)),Df_x(V_2(x))=((1,0,0,...,0),(0,1,0,...,0))$ for each $x$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose we're given two vector fields $V_1,V_2$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $V_1(x),V_2(x)$ are linearly independent for each $x$. Then, Is is possible
to find a diffeomorphism $f$ from a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ to a neighborhood $V$ of $0$ such that $(Df_x(V_1(x)),Df_x(V_2(x))=(1,0,0,...,0),(0,1,0,...,0)$ for each $x$

Answer (score 1):

The existence of such a diffeomorphism just means that $V_1,V_2$ are *coordinate fields*. Now, this is known to be equivalent to the condition that $V_1,V_2$ commute: 
$$[V_1,V_2]=V_1V_2-V_2V_1=0.$$  This is a classical result on fields and flows usually found in any Differential Geometry text dealing with the *Lie bracket*. More explicitely, if $V_k=(\dots,V_k^i,\dots)$ the condition reads as follows:
$$
\sum_i\Big(V_1^i\frac{\partial V_2^j}{\partial x_i}-V_2^i\frac{\partial V_1^j}{\partial x_i}\Big)=0\quad \text{for $1\le j\le n$}.
$$